# How is this EMF image A4 sized?

Tags: image, reverse-engineering, gdi, file-format, .emf

An EMF file made by Adobe Illustrator (I do not know which version, but it has one of the early style EMR headers) is supposed to be A4 sized and I don't understand how it could be.  The file has these EMR records:

```
U_EMRHEADER                   record:    0 type:  1 offset:       0 size:     116
   rclBounds:      {255,-925,1377,-132} 
   rclFrame:       {7969,-28906,43031,-4125}  **350.63 x 247.82 mm**
   dSignature:     0x464D4520
   nVersion:       0x00010000
   nBytes:         1924
   nRecords:       54
   nHandles:       4
   sReserved:      0
   nDescription:   13
   offDescription: 88
      Desc. A:  Adobe Systems
      Desc. B:  
   nPalEntries:    0
   szlDevice:      {1024,768} 
   szlMillimeters: {320,240} 
U_EMRSETMAPMODE               record:    1 type: 17 offset:     116 size:      12
   iMode:          0x00000008       **MM_ANISOTROPIC**
U_EMRSETWINDOWORGEX           record:    3 type: 10 offset:     140 size:      16
   ptlOrigin:      {0,0}
U_EMRSETVIEWPORTORGEX         record:    4 type: 12 offset:     156 size:      16
   ptlOrigin:      {0,0}
U_EMRSETWINDOWEXTEX           record:    5 type:  9 offset:     172 size:      16
   szlExtent:      {10104,7143}
U_EMRSETVIEWPORTEXTEX         record:    6 type: 11 offset:     188 size:      16
   szlExtent:      {3368,2381}
```

The rclFrame fields normally set the page size but A4 is 297 x 210 mm, not 350.63 x 247.82 mm.  However 350.63 x 247.82 is the correct ratio for A4.  The only way I could finagle an A4 size out of these numbers was by treating the rclFrame values as MM_HIENGLISH and then using the 1/3 scale factor from EMRSETWINDOWEXTEX/EMRSETVIEWPORTEXTEX this way:

```
 35.063" * 1/3 = 11.69"
 24.782" * 1/3 = 8.26"
```

But that would mean that the program could not determine the size of the page until it had seen those latter two records.  Also nowhere could I find any documentation that said this sort of thing goes on.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4):

I think your EMF may contain more information than is indicated by the diagnostic dump.
The supplied EMR_HEADER record has nVersion set to 0x00010000 so the record aditionally contains these fields starting after szlMillimeters:

```
    public uint     cbPixelFormat;
    public uint     offPixelFormat;
    public uint     bOpenGL;
    public SIZE     szlMicrometers;
```

The values of these fields are missing from the supplied diagnostic dump. Here's a hex dump from the head of an XP emf file I had on my machine:

```
 0: 01 00 00 00 6c 00 00 00 58 07 00 00 03 02 00 00  | ....l...X....... |
10: aa 0b 00 00 1f 04 00 00 95 1f 00 00 07 09 00 00  | ................ |
20: 07 31 00 00 15 11 00 00 20 45 4d 46 00 00 01 00  | .1...... EMF.... |
30: 44 07 00 00 2e 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  | D............... |
40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 61 13 00 00 68 1b 00 00  | ........a...h... |
50: d2 00 00 00 29 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  | ....)........... |
60: 00 00 00 00 50 34 03 00 28 88 04 00              | ....P4..(...     |
```

In this snippet, the szlMicrometers field is the last pair of DWORDs. Their values are 0x00033450, 0x00048828, and expressed in decimal in thousandths of a mm these values are 210000, 297000